# jQuery selector for an HTML element whose id contains a point (.)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The element:

```
<input type='text' id='Customer.name' value='' />
```

The invalid jQuery selector:

```
$('#Customer.name')
```

Does anyone know what the selector should be for this element?

Comment: [Question 6](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F) from jQuery FAQ.

Comment: FYI, if you have any influence over the content, it's certainly best to stay away from punctuation in id names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$('input[id="Customer.name"]')
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/HFpEE/

Comment: if there a way to get teh element by css #Customer.name{ ...} doesnot work,!! ay way to get it by css

Answer (score 19):

You can escape the period character with two backslashes:

```
$('#Customer\\.name')
```

Comment: This selector is perfectly valid although in IE9 even when the html element is there, `$('#Customer\\.name').length` returns 0. However, `$('input[id="Customer.name"]')` returns 1 (!?!)

Answer (score 5):

From the jquery documentation:

```
$("#Customer\\.name")
```

[jQuery FAQ](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)